# Is it possible to use "implicit" generic type parameters in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic type:

```
public class Source<T> where T : ISomeInterface<X> //...
```

Now, my problem is, I really don't want to modify `Source<T>` `to Source<T,X>`, but I want to use X inside Source.
Is it possible in any way?

Comment: You can create a factory method for the creation of `Source<T,X>` types. This will save you from having to write all the generic arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's no way of expressing that. If you want to be able to refer to `X` within `Source`, it has to be a type parameter.

Bear in mind that `T` could implement (say) `ISomeInterface<string>` *and* `ISomeInterface<int>`. What would `X` be in that case?

Comment: is it a "missing feature", or am I tackling the problem wrong?

Comment: @TDaver: It's hard to say without knowing details of what you're trying to do, or why you don't want X to be a type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a generic type, you're telling the compiler that you're going to provide the actual type when creating a concrete instance.
With your code, if you tried to do a

```
Source<string> s = new Source<string>();
```

the compiler would know that T is actually a string in the class, but you're not giving the compiler any info on what X would be. 
However, depending on what you want to do, you may be able to use a "has a" relationship with Interface with a naked type constraint instead of using inheritance.
The following code does compile, for instance:

```
public interface ISomeInterface<X> 
{
    void SomeMethod(X someparam);
}    

public class Source<T> 
{
    public void MyMethod<X>(ISomeInterface<X> someConcreteInstance) where X:T
    {

    }        
}
```